# Displaying results from a distributed search

Tags: search

Does anyone have some tips for displaying search results that come in batches and asynchronously from multiple locations? Is this a solved problem?

---Edit---

I mean from multiple devices and hence multiple databases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Kayak](http://www.kayak.com) does this when searching for flights; it queries a bunch of airlines in parallel and displays results as they come in, maintaining the sort you specified (by price, departure time, or whatever).

Comment: Thanks! I'm doing something similar myself. I'm trying to not have the users wait like when using kayak or the other websites. 

The catch I think is (feel free to correct me) that in most scenarios users on kayak only want to care about the top few searches may be 2-3 if they don't like them they filter the searches as they want or search again. In my case they will look for one particular thing vs the best in a category. Hence I'm a little skeptical about continuously refreshing the screen, since the users will be reading a lot of the  results that come in. 

Am I making sense?

Comment: Ah, yes that's a slightly different use case.  Perhaps refresh + some visual discriminator (indentation, changebars, etc) for the newly-added items?  I'm assuming order still matters to you else you'd just append to the bottom as stuff came in.

Answer (score 0):

well, ok, I guess you're meaning different databases. If the results all come in at different times you will not be able to produce a fair result set to the user.

You could scope the search. For each database create a separate scope and allow the user to select at time of submission.

examples of scoped search:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have to show results of all types from all locations and reorder the results as they come in (approximately). But I do have a filter in place to show specific results. :)